# Using keyframe() to display nested dictionary info using Python in Maya

Tags: python, animation, scripting, maya, keyframe

I need help doing the following:

Using the keyframe method (and flags) to extract information from a selected set of keys to store them in a nested dictionary. These keyframes correspond to an animation that has the all the keyframes copied for pasting onto other joints as needed.  I've been combing through the documentation and different sources on the net but am running into animation terms and concepts I'm not familiar with.
I will later access this dictionary to display the keyframe information in a nicely formatted window so the artist I'm writing this for can see what the effect will be before pasting the animation.

My code for this part so far:

```
else:
    key_list = mc.copyKey()

    # check to see if window exists already
    if mc.window(copyAnim, exists = True):
        mc.deleteUI(copyAnim)

    # create window
    copyAnim = mc.window(title="Transfer Animation Tool", backgroundColor= [0.3,0.3,0.3],sizeable=False,resizeToFitChildren=True)

    #set the layout for UI
    mc.columnLayout(adjustableColumn=True)
    tx_src = mc.textFieldGrp(label="Source Object", editable=False, text=sel[0])
    int_offset = mc.intFieldGrp(label="Frame Offset Amount", value1=0)

    #displaying what info will be transferred - here is where I would use   
    #keyframe() instead -- getting an error because copyKey() returns an
    #int which is not iterable. As you can see the return value for copyKey 
    #is being stored in key_list.
    for key in key_list:
    display_info = mc.textFieldGrp(label="Copy Value", editable=False, text=key_list[item])
```

Link to documentation:
http://download.autodesk.com/us/maya/2011help/CommandsPython/keyframe.html

Comment: Are you looking for advice on how to display the information in the UI, or on how to interpret the info?

Comment: What I'm looking for is how to store the key frame info in a nested dictionary using the keyframe method (or another appropriate method). I'm not sure how to use the flags for this method.  I will deal with the GUI display issue later.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like the only flags you need for this application are `-vc`, which gets you the values and `-tc`, which get you the times (when combined with the `-q` flag which does the query.

If all you want is a dictionary of keys to values, it's basically just using `dict()` and [`zip()`](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/functions.html#zip):

```
def keys_as_dictionary(channel):
    """return a dictionay of times:values for <channel>"""
    keys = cmds.keyframe(channel, q=True, tc=True) or []
    values = cmds.keyframe(channel, q=True, vc=True) or []
    return dict(zip(keys, values))

def channels(object):
    """return a dictionary of <plug>:<channel_dict> for each animated plug on <object>"""
    keys = cmds.keyframe(object, n=True, q=True)
    result = {}

    for k in keys:
        plugs = cmds.listConnections(k, p=True)[0]
        result[plugs]= keys_as_dictionary(k)
    return result
```

Calling `channels()` on an object will give you back a dictionary keyed by animation curve where the values are dictionaries of times and values:

```
import pprint
pprint.pprint(channels('pCube2'))

{u'pCube2.translateX': {4.955: 4.164464499411458,
                        10.89: -0.8212519883789916,
                        15.465: -0.6405074625130949,
                        22.65: -1.7965970091598258},
 u'pCube2.translateY': {4.955: 8.271115169656772,
                        10.89: 0.3862609404272041,
                        15.465: 7.77669517461548,
                        22.65: 0.6892861215369379},
 u'pCube2.translateZ': {4.955: -1.4066258181614297,
                        10.89: -4.891368771063121,
                        15.465: 4.340776804349586,
                        22.65: -3.5676492042261776}}
```

*word of warning*:  this should work for plain animated objects, but is not doing anything smart about shared animation curves, instanced nodes, constraints or locked channels.... FYI....